# Search results- Anonymous users get 401 for 'http://sitename.com/subsite/pages' url

Tags: 2010, search

Anonymous users are having issues with SharePoint 2010 search results where a subsite's welcome page is being returned in the results with a URL of - **'http://sitename.com/subsite/pages'**  instead of **'http://sitename.com/subsite/pages/default.aspx'** OR **'http://sitename.com/subsite/'**

When the user clicks on the **'http://sitename.com/subsite/pages'** link they are being redirected to the login page.

The user has no issue browsing to these pages using the navigation on the site, or just appending '/default.aspx' or by removing '/pages' from the URL -  **'http://sitename.com/subsite/pages'** returned in the results.

The **viewformpageslockdown** feature has been enabled on the site and anoymous access has been granted to the whole site.

Any ideas how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a publishing portal? On team sites OSSSearchResults.aspx isn't designed for anonymous access, Search/Results.aspx is. Your site basically needs to be a publishing site for it to work.

Comment: Yes, it is a publishing site. Search is returning results but when an anonymous user clicks on a result item for a subsite welcome page with the url **http://sitename.com/subsite/pages**, we get redirected to the login page. I've added an IIS rewrite rule for the anonymous site to redirect the URL **http://sitename.com/subsite/pages** to **http://sitename.com/subsite/** and it seems to work. Just wondering if this is the correct approach?

Comment: Change the Indexing ASPX Page Content setting to "Always index all Webparts on this site" (In Site Settings, Search and Offline Availability I think), clear your indexes and do a full crawl, that should be your solution. You shouldn't need to redirect.